# How to iterate and compare values of keys in list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that look like this:

```
dict1 = {'id':'a12','key':'value'}
dict2 = [{'id':'a12'},{'id':'a12'}]
```

How do I iterate through `dict2` and compare whether `id` value matches value in `dict1` and append the dictionary in `dict2` to a list if there is a match?

I have written this code:

```
lst=[]
for i in dict2:
    if dict1['id'] == dict2['id']:
        lst.append(i)
```

I get this error when I run the above code:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong in the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.  You are doing nothing wrong in your comparison.  The problem is that `dict2` is, in fact, an array of dictionaries, so there's no such thing as `dict2['id']` -- you're thinking of `i['id']`.

```
lst=[]
for i in dict2:
    if dict1['id'] == i['id']:
        lst.append(i)
```

Comment: both of your answers are the same! thank you so much! – RustyShackleford just now

Answer (score 2):

`dict2` is array, not dictionary. you need to use the `i` variable inside the for loop:

```py
lst=[]
for i in dict2:
    if dict1['id'] == i['id']:
        lst.append(i)
```

Comment: both of your answers are the same! thank you so much!